# Does air pressure have some effect on weight?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, pressure, fluid-statics, free-body-diagram, density

If one measure some object in air and then measure it in vacuum will there be any difference in weight?

Comment: Air pressure must result in a force which is always neglected or id s is it?

Answer (score 0):

As you see apparent weight in fluid mechanics similarly air is also a fluid but the change in weight observed is very less due to its low density.